# C++ OpenMP parallel for loop with synchronization?

Tags: c++, openmp

this is my first time working with OpenMP, and I have a beginner knowledge in parallel programming.

What I want to know is how do I do a OpenMP parallel simulation that is synchronized by time?

In this simulation, agents would be multithreaded, and they will perform some tasks which could be dependent on each other per loop.

Below is a (unfinished) POC code that is what I am thinking of:

```
void simulateNext(Agent agent, int time) {
    
  // do simulation stuff

}

int main() {
      // TODO add initialise code for all agents

      int max_time = 10000;
      int num_agents = 1000

      for (int i = 0; i < max_time; i++) {
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int j=0; j < num_agents; j++) {
            simulateNext(agents[j], i);
        }
    }

}
```

I am very sure this will work, however the parallel for does not seem to be the best way to do it! I am guessing that the implementation above means that for every iteration of i, I will spawn and destroy threads? That seems like a waste if that is indeed the case.

Is there a better way do this? I was thinking of the following code which could be better but I am not sure it even works.

```
int max_time = 10000;

void runSimulation(Agent agent) {
  
  for (int i = 0; i < max_time; i++) {
      // do simulation stuff

      #pragma omp barrier
  }

}

int main() {
      // TODO add initialise code for all agents

      int num_agents = 1000

      #pragma omp parallel for
      for (int j=0; j < num_agents; j++) {
          runSimulation(agents[j]);
      }

}
```

Comment: Do not worry about spawning and destroying threads, OpenMP runtime handles it efficiently (in practice will not destroy them). However, you should carefully avoid potential race conditions and consider dependencies. To help you in this process the best would be if you could provide a [mre].

Comment: Creating/Destroying threads is not a problem as pointed out by Laci, but synchronizations and work sharing can be. The code can be slightly improved by splitting the directive to `#pragma omp parallel` and `#pragma omp for`. Consider using the `schedule(static) nowait` clause to avoid an implicit barrier at the end of the parallel for. This assume the simulation of the agent is independent of others. If this is not the case, then the problem is not OpenMP but this limitation and you need to tell us more about `simulateNext`. Besides, I think using a barrier in a parallel-for is a very bad idea

Comment: Your design may work, however, I would suggest you also try having the time loop outermost and sequential, and then have the parallel loop over agents inside.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Using a barrier inside a parallel for is worse that `a bad idea`, it is non-standard conforming, since a barrier must be reached by all threads, but the number of times each thread executes a for-body need not be the same. (Consider `for (int i-0l; i<i; i++)` :-))

Comment: A general rule with OpenMP: simple and straightforward directives generally work well (as long as we understand what they are doing). In other words write the simplest version of what you want to do, time it, and dig for more complex versions only if you're not satisfied with the obtained speed-up :)

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to write this is something like this

```
int main() {
  // TODO add initialise code for all agents
  
  int max_time = 10000;
  int num_agents = 1000
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < max_time; i++) {
    #pragma omp for
      for (int j=0; j < num_agents; j++) {
        simulateNext(agents[j], i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is already an implicit barrier at the end of the `omp for`, and it is entirely reasonable simply to have each thread execute the outer loop.